# How to select unique columns from X columns but show X + Y columns from the results in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, impala

This table is on our impala cluster, although, the impala shell seems very similar to SQL.  I have very little SQL or Impala experience, outside of doing extremely simple queries so this problem might be way above my experience and pay grade.

I need to get some data from our db using impala.  There are other columns in the table but my command grabs these 3 columns I'm interested in.  The data/result can look like this:

```
time | server | data
  0  |   A    | 500
  0  |   B    | 200
  0  |   C    | 300
  1  |   A    | 100
  1  |   A    | 400
  1  |   B    | 200
  1  |   C    | 300
  2  |   A    | 900
  2  |   B    | 800
  2  |   C    | 700
  2  |   C    | 600
```

Ideally, the data should look like time 0, where each server only shows up once for each time value.  However, there's a bug and as shown, a server can show up more than once for a time value.  And it's not the same server that shows up more than once per time value either, as shown in the example above.

In any case, what impala-shell/SQL command do I read up/look up to tell it to select distinct time and server but to choose the larger of the two data values?  I don't know how to proceed past:

```
select distinct time, server from table;
```

If this is too hard or complicated, perhaps someone can point me to a command that selects distinct time and server but prints the first value of data it finds for the distinct pair of time and server.

Comment: If there are several `time + server` pairs, `data` from what line must be returned?

Comment: @zerkms, thx for your interest and help.  i'd like to print out the larger value if possible, like in time = 1 for server A, i'd like to print out 400.

Comment: if it's too complicated, then i'll just list out the first value we come across for the time/server pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the unique time and server values along with the largest data value you could use a query with a `GROUP BY`, as follows:

```
SELECT TIME, SERVER, MAX(DATA)
  FROM TABLE
  GROUP BY TIME, SERVER
  ORDER BY TIME, SERVER;
```

Hope this helps.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: This particular ORDER BY is implicit in the GROUP BY

Comment: That may be true in MySQL at present, but it's certainly not so in other DBMS's. In my experience adding an ORDER BY along with the GROUP BY is a good habit to cultivate - it would have saved my company several months of work when we upgraded from Oracle 9 to Oracle 10. YMMV.

Comment: Is that true? Good to know

Comment: Yep. Found it while testing 10g when planning for the upgrade. Not hard work, but long, tedious, and...tedious. *Much* easier to put an ORDER BY in every time a GROUP BY is used. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table test_tabl(time int, server varchar(10), data int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into test_tabl values(0, 'A', 500), (0, 'B', 200), (0, 'C', 300);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into test_tabl values(1, 'A', 100), (1, 'A', 400), (1, 'B', 200), (1, 'C', 300);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into test_tabl values(2, 'A', 900), (2, 'B', 800), (2, 'C', 700), (2, 'C', 600);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test_tabl;
+------+--------+------+
| time | server | data |
+------+--------+------+
|    0 | A      |  500 |
|    0 | B      |  200 |
|    0 | C      |  300 |
|    1 | A      |  100 |
|    1 | A      |  400 |
|    1 | B      |  200 |
|    1 | C      |  300 |
|    2 | A      |  900 |
|    2 | B      |  800 |
|    2 | C      |  700 |
|    2 | C      |  600 |
+------+--------+------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> select time, server, max(data) from test_tabl group by time, server;
+------+--------+-----------+
| time | server | max(data) |
+------+--------+-----------+
|    0 | A      |       500 |
|    0 | B      |       200 |
|    0 | C      |       300 |
|    1 | A      |       400 |
|    1 | B      |       200 |
|    1 | C      |       300 |
|    2 | A      |       900 |
|    2 | B      |       800 |
|    2 | C      |       700 |
+------+--------+-----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```